# how to login user by facebook in smartfoxserver?

Tags: smartfoxserver

i want my user to login by facebook login ,i am using this code in client side

`sfsClient.login("myext", param1, "");` and in extension response i want

```
if (event.params.dataObj.success) 
{ 
sfsClient.myUserId = event.params.dataObj.userId; 
currentUser.userId = event.params.dataObj.userId;; 
sfsClient.myUserName = event.params.dataObj.userName; 
currentUser.userName = event.params.dataObj.userName; 
dispatchEvent(new myEvent(myEvent.onLogMessage, "Getting Room List")); 
sfsClient.getRoomList();
```

can anybody explain how should be my extensionside code,ADVANCE THANK YOU

Comment: user the facebookid as the username, facebook usernames are null a lot of times

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use the facebook Api for java , here's a usefull link :
[Java Facebook Api](http://straylink.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/logging-in-with-facebook-java-api/)